# Can I run multiple independent test-control split tests on the same target audience?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I'm interested in the statistical validity of performing multiple randomised test-control experiments among the same target audience at the same time.

As a simple example consider below:

1. I have 30,000 app users.
2. I promote a discount on some shoes to 28,000 and don't promote to 2,000 by randomly assigning into test & control groups.
3. I promote another discount on some shirts to a newly selected random 28,000 and don't promote to the 2,000 again.

2 and 3 were done within days of each other and sales were measured for some weeks after.

A colleague is concerned that the results from 3 aren't valid since the promotion from 2 would have compromised the control group.

Our objective is to measure the increased propensity to purchase the products (i.e. test propensity / control propensity). Based on that, my intuition was that because the effects of the first promo would be felt to the same degree in the the test and control groups of the second experiment (on average due to an independent random assignment), that results would still be valid in inferring the increased value attributable to the second experiment.

Is that the correct? I know there is multivariate testing also where we could look into combinations, however my company isn't really at the maturity to analyse that yet.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Do I understand correctly that you already performed all of this? If not, two pointers: 1) You are better off having 4 groups: control, discount item A, discount item B, discount both. That way you can estimate an interaction, which will allow you to see the effect of having both on sale as opposed to either. 2) Is there a particular reason why your control group is that much smaller than the other group? If there are no disadvantages (like missing out on sales), you should strive for a balanced design.

Comment: I think @FransRodenburg's comment practically answers your question. Even if you have already done the experiment, you can filter out the four groups from your data and then test. If you are unclear on how to do that, please clarify. Also please clarify how you are defining "test propensity" and "control propensity".

Comment: Thanks @FransRodenburg. To clarify, in general I'm most interested in the statistical validity of comparing _independent_ test-controls without interaction effects across multiple campaigns that may overlap in duration, but that aren't necessarily related or planned together. We aren't at a maturity to plan / perform / analyse in multiple streams as recommended and are most interested in just the basic "Campaign X increased demand by Y whereas campaign Z did by Q". "X propensity" - proportion of audience X 'converted' to purchase. Thanks!

Comment: [In the presence of an interaction, you cannot interpret the main effects separately.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality) Only after finding that the interaction effect is negligible can you do what you propose. I can summarize this in an answer if this satisfies your interest in the statistical validity of the approach.